# Как в tkinter привязать выполнение функции не к клавише, а ко времени?

Tags: python, tkinter

Привожу кусок рабочего кода. Как видно, идёт обновление картинки по UDP, но сейчас обновление идёт, когда нажимается клавиша энтер. Но как привязать эвент ко времени?

```
def get_img(event):
    image_byte_array, addr = UDP_rsv.recvfrom(12288)
    im = Image.frombuffer("RGB", (64, 64), image_byte_array, "raw", "RGB", 0, 
    resized_img = im.resize((64 * 5, 64 * 5), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
    panel.configure(image=pic)
    panel.image_names(pic)
app = tk.Tk()
pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test1.png"))
panel = tk.Label(app, image=pic)
panel.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
app.bind("<Return>", get_img)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: К какому времени?

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать видеопоток. Т.е. Чтоб функция вызывалась раз в 300 миллисекунд.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что это самый подходящий способ организовать видеопоток, но решение в лоб простое - `app.after(300, get_img)`.

Comment: Как вариант, это можно сделать ещё и таймером.